# Issue with second window in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Please, tell anybody,
Q1- how to create form using grid in second window (tkinter)?
Q2- how to create menubar in second window(tkinter)? Please tell

Comment: I didn't understand your first question. For the second one, refer my answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create menubars using the `Menu` function in tkinter.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menu

root = Tk()
root.title("Menubars with tkinter")
root.geometry("500x500")

def print_hello():
    print("Hello, World!")

def print_bye():
    print("Bye!")

menu = Menu(root)    # Creating a menubar
main_menu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)    # Creating a menu inside the menubar

main_menu.add_command(label="Print 'Hello World'", command=print_hello)
main_menu.add_command(label="Print 'Bye'", command=print_bye)

menu.add_cascade(label="Main", menu=main_menu)    # Adding cascade

root.config(menu=menu)    # So that the menubar is visible
root.mainloop()    # Applying mainloop
```